# Like std::is_pointer and std::is_integral, how to implement std::is_cstring_pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

Like `std::is_pointer` and `std::is_integral`, how to implement `std::is_cstring_pointer`?

I want to check the pointer is a c type string pointer or not, is it possible?

How to achieve this goal?

Comment: what did you try? Just check if the type is `char[n]` for some `n`

Comment: There are 2 things to consider: the pointer points to char(s) and if the char array is 0-terminated. According to this: what would you want to consider as cstring_pointer ?

Comment: Why do you need a utility function for this? std::is_integral is useful because there are different data types that are an integral type. For cstrings you either have a const char* or not, what is there to check?

Comment: @Eric You can have a non-const `char*` too, as well as volatile qualified ones, rare as they may be. That's four pointed-to types. And the pointer itself may be qualified so that's 16 types in total.

Comment: There is no way, in general, to know whether an arbitrary pointer points at a valid nul-terminated char array. `char ch; const char* ptr = &ch;`.

Answer (score 2):

It is fairly simple to combine the existing type traits:

```
template <class T>
struct is_char_ptr
    : std::integral_constant<bool,
        std::is_pointer_v<T>
        && std::is_same_v<char,
          typename std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_pointer_t<T>>>>
{};
```

Note that a pointer to char may point to a null terminated string, or it might not. Whether it does will not affect the type.

Comment: "Note that a pointer to char may point to a null terminated string, or it might not." So can I make the conclusion that there is no way to know the `char*` pointer points to a null-terminated string or not?

Comment: @John Based on the type, there is no way.

Comment: Could you please recommend some documents for me to go through to fully understand this code snippet? For me, it's not a simple code snippet.

Comment: @John cppreference is pretty good in my opinion.

Comment: I see, Thank you.

Comment: A related question, I use a similar expression, but it could not filter out the variable with the type of `char*`. See here, https://stackoverflow.com/q/65301158/13611002