# std::enable_if to filter out the argument with the type of char*

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, type-traits, enable-if

Why `char* pstr="hello"; pushArg(pstr);` still invoke such template?

You see there is `&&(!std::is_same<char, typename std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_pointer_t<T>>>::value)` already.

```
template <typename T, 
          typename std::enable_if<(!std::is_same<lua_CFunction, T*>::value)
                               &&   std::is_pointer<T>::value
                               && (!std::is_same<std::string*, T>::value)
                               && (!std::is_same<char, typename std::remove_cv<std::remove_pointer<T>>>::value)
                               && (!std::is_same<unsigned char, typename std::remove_cv<std::remove_pointer<T>>>::value)
int pushArg(T& val)
{

}
```

Comment: `char* pstr="hello";` won't compile, missing `const`.

Comment: @Jarod42 It's a warning when -Wall or alike is not enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have tagged your answer with `C++11` but you use `std::remove_cv_t` from C++14.

In C++17, your function would look like this:

```cpp
template <typename T, 
          std::enable_if_t<
            std::is_pointer_v< T >
            && !std::is_same_v< std::string* , T >
            && !std::is_same_v< char         , typename std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_pointer_t<T>> >
            && !std::is_same_v< unsigned char, typename std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_pointer_t<T>> >,
            void
          >* = nullptr
         >
int pushArg(T& val) {
    return 0;
}
```

and the error will be thrown in case of passing `char *pstr = "hello"`.

And in C++11, you are missing `typename std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type>::type` part. Full code below:

```cpp
template <typename T, 
          typename std::enable_if<
            std::is_pointer< T >::value
            && !std::is_same< std::string* , T >::value
            && !std::is_same< char         , typename std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type>::type >::value
            && !std::is_same< unsigned char, typename std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type>::type >::value,
            void
          >::type* = nullptr
         >
int pushArg(T& val) {
    return 0;
}
```

[DEMO](https://godbolt.org/#z: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%2BX3zvSpt4DAoEFtiMAIOHU1Mx50ZgB2WRaxFLAh9WhTDazZ87B%2Br84D3oKYjC%2BWgIE6QCnznc1LSVbxFhXKRJAQZRWFQZCfznY9T3PS8EI%2BSCRl/cR/0GbpWBAQYzEGUhTEGDZaNQKidDkORMV6foDlGThaIIKjGM6boAGsQAFSQADoRm4ABOAAOAUZO4MxOEUh9OEkXhKMGbhaPoxjSGYwZaIUEANlIfiGPI0g4FgGBEBQVAgTwdgyAoCA0Gc1yQGATgNkkUgqBchlTIgZwBNo5w7EyR4ItITzjXoAB5WhWFiqzSCwUDRHYOL8CWVJ3VMjLMAADxSAwATirttIM1g8GcT5iEePQsCo3iLOIPAjHa6yaHoJg2A4Hh%2BEEYRRBQNiZCEBrTMgbpUG3QJioAWixFcJBkOROA6goUiKUwICsBpTC8KxylieJBF8fwDpO66IgOi7KncGpklSYpmnut7CjSZpnvaV7FC%2B/RckEWpSgBq7OG6BROIGLgKKomi6LiozSoUlaBW4KZgGQZApj8iTJCmCBcEIEgZkuLwpj0Ly3CpkYYdpqbpD4iKhNIUSzHM7TdNIHqedRjKjJMsyLI5mz7IgJBegIY8CHIShPO8FyqjO/AiCB/rGBYXKRoAd0%2BbxeqR6i9LRqieKmA3CAQKYMYFLGcbxgmickdmrM51DmCwdwIKEKj%2BcF8z9KYqixfMyzBJEkARgfCSBR5zgRg2MxuDk1PJDkh8BUDwYRgtkWI4lr2zY94WDNF0uY9Id1iH8DRuCAA%3D)

Comment: extra `typename` can be removed in your C++17 version (only the one for `T` is needed)